# C# Way to name Main() method by yourself?

Tags: c#, program-entry-point

Quick question, is there a way to call your main method whatever you like ? Or does it have to be called "Main()" ?

Comment: This has never come up from me, just because you can have only one line inside of Main() and from there call whatever you want.  I am interested in the answer though..

Comment: Is there a reason other than curiosity? 

Someone has a quote that goes like this "If debugging is twice as hard as writing new code, then by definition you aren't smart enough to debug the 'smartest' code you can come up with." Messing with conventions falls squarely in that category.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note this is a C# convention, not a .NET Runtime convention.  You can name your method whatever you'd like in IL:

```
.module Mane.exe
.subsystem 3
.corflags 9

.assembly extern mscorlib
{
  .publickeytoken = (B7 7A 5C 56 19 34 E0 89)
  .ver 2:0:0:0
}

.assembly Mane
{
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute::.ctor(bool) = ( 01 00 00 00 00 ) 
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.CLSCompliantAttribute::.ctor(bool) = ( 01 00 01 00 00 ) 
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Reflection.AssemblyFileVersionAttribute::.ctor(string) = ( 01 00 07 31 2E 30 2E 30 2E 30 00 00 )
    .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Resources.NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute::.ctor(string) = ( 01 00 05 65 6E 2D 55 53 00 00 )

    .permissionset reqmin
               = {[mscorlib]System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionAttribute = {property bool 'Execution' = bool(true)}}
    .hash algorithm 0x00008004
    .ver 1:0:0:0
}

.namespace Mane
{
    .class private abstract auto ansi sealed beforefieldinit Program extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
        .method private hidebysig static void Mane() cil managed
        {
            .entrypoint
            .maxstack 1
            ldstr "Hello, World!"
            call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(class System.String)
            ret
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks great answer. Really interesting

Comment: You're very welcome, thanks for the kudos.  As an afterthought, I wonder if a tool like PostSharp could inject the appropriate part of the IL (.entrypoint) into a method that was decorated with a particular attribute and therefore obviate the C# "limitation" of the entry point needing to be named Main().

Answer (score 5):

You can call your main method something else, but it won't be called as the first method in your application unless it is called `Main`. There are a few other requirements and things to note too. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx):

- The Main method is the entry point of your program, where the program control starts and ends.
- It is declared inside a class or struct. It must be static and it should not be public.
- It can either have a void or int return type.
- The Main method can be declared with or without parameters.
- Parameters can be read as zero-indexed command line arguments.
- Unlike C and C++, the name of the program is not treated as the first command line argument.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a way to do it on the C# side of things but if you are willing to edit your IL it is easy enough to go in and add .entrypoint to the function in IL.  Check out the CLI entry on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it has to be called Main. [See Main() and Command Line Arguments (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It has to be called Main().

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be called `Main()` since it's the entry point for the application.

The name and restrictions are defined by the Framework. Here's the MSDN page for reference:

[Main (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx)

Comment: Apparently this is a C# convention, not a .NET Framework convention.

Answer (score 1):

It has to be called Main.

If you really wanted to, you could create your own method, and just call it as the one-and-only line of code in Main.

```
public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    Mane(args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope ... Main is standard. What you can do though is change the class that hosts the Main method from the project property's "Startup object" setting

But really, why would you want to? everyone knows that it's main ... so you'd be confusing other developers that may look at your code

Answer (score 1):

From "[Main () and Other Methods (C# vs Java)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506.aspx)":

> Every C# application must contain a single Main method specifying where program execution is to begin.

Answer (score 0):

As of C# 9.0, a `Main` method is [no longer required](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/welcome-to-c-9-0/#top-level-programs):

> In C# 9.0 you can just choose to write your main program at the top level instead:
>
> ```
> using System;
>
> Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
> ```
>
> Any statement is allowed. The program has to occur after the `using`s and before any type or namespace declarations in the file, and you can only do this in one file, just as you can have only one `Main` method today.

This will save some boilerplate code and can be useful for a quick console program to test something, but for anything more serious I'd still recommend using `Main`; if you're looking for the entry point of a program, it's easy to search for `Main(` in the entire solution but not so easy to search for the *lack* of a namespace/class/method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change your the name of "Main" as it is the void that is always going to run first by default. However, you can create another void and instantly call it through main if you want, although it might just be simpeler to use Main();

```
using System;
class Program 
{


static void Main(string[] args) // Manages the login input
{
     OnScriptStarted();
}
static void OnScriptStarted()
{
    // code goes here
}
```